# how to update edittext on datepicker set button

Tags: java, android

this is my code which work fine updare edittext but problem is edittext not update imediately until i click again on edittext  tell me how do i update edittext on datepicker dailog (positive button)    h date picker display two default button  positive and negative how do i update editteext on positive button  help me please

```
    EditText edtKeyword;
    String selectedDate;
int mYear,mMonth,mDay ;

    DateFormat fmtDateAndTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        edtKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtKeyword);

        edtKeyword.setClickable(true);

        edtKeyword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(MenuList.this, d, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR),                   
                     myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
         myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                mYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                selectedDate= mMonth+"-"+mDay+"-"+mYear;

                edtKeyword.setText(selectedDate);               
        }
    });        

    edtKeyword.setText(fmtDateAndTime.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: how to update edittext on imediately on set buttoin which wil show on screen

Comment: no one help me  tell how update editetxt on datepickerdailog positive button????

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code. It works fine for me. Please try it once

```
private int pYear = 1970;
private int pMonth = 1;
private int pDay = 1;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

Then in onCreate:

```
    edt_birth.setKeyListener(null);
    edt_birth.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            return false;
        }
    });


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth,
                pDay);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        pYear = year;
        pMonth = monthOfYear;
        pDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};

private void updateDisplay() {
    int temp = pMonth + 1;
    edt_birth.setText(pDay + "/" + temp + "/" + pYear);
    }
```

This will update your edittext.

Comment: edt_birth is edittext????

Comment: yep.. its an edittext..

Comment: I found your code so confusing. Thats why I gave you my code. You can match and arrange it according to your requirement

Comment: my code work fine but need two times click on edittext  how do i update my edittext on datepicker(Set) button??

Comment: datapicker show two button positive and negative??  how do i update editext on positive button???